# How to fix randomization in sklearn

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-seed

I am trying to fix the randomization in my code but every time I run, I get different best score and best parameters. The results are no too far apart, but how can I fix the result to get the same best score and parameters every time I run?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 27)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)


clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=None)

parameter_grid = {'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
                  'splitter': ['best', 'random'],
                  'max_depth': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,8,10,20,30,50],
                  'max_features': [10,20,30,40,50]
                 }

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None)
skf.get_n_splits(X_train, y_train)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=parameter_grid, cv=skf, scoring='precision')

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Best score: {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))
print('Best parameters: {}'.format(grid_search.best_params_))

clf = grid_search.best_estimator_

y_pred_iris = clf.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred),"\n")
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred),"\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get reproducible results, *every* source of randomness in your code must be explicitly **seeded** (and even then, you must be careful that the implicit assumption of *all other being equal* actually holds - see [Why does the importance parameter influence performance of Random Forest in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influence-performance-of-random-forest-in-r) for a case where it does not).

There are three parts in your code that inherently include a random element:

- `train_test_split`
- `DecisionTreeClassifier`
- `StratifiedKFold`

You correctly seed the first one (using `random_state=27`), but you fail to do so for the other two, leaving `random_state=None` in both of them.

What you should do is simply replace the two cases of `random_state=None` in your code with an explicit seed, as you have done for `train_test_split`; it doesn't have to be any specific number, or even the same for all cases, it just needs to be explicitly set.

Comment: The random_state=False should achieve the same result according to the documentation. but apparently it doesn't. However, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you very much.