# GridSearchCV not choosing the best hyperparameters for xgboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am currently working on developing a regression model with xgboost. Since xgboost has multiple hyperparameters, I have added the cross validation logic with `GridSearchCV()`. As a trial, I set `max_depth: [2,3]`. My python code is as below.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
​
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor()
​
# Obtain the best hyper parameter
scorer=make_scorer(mean_squared_error, False)
params = {'max_depth': [2,3], 
          'eta': [0.1], 
          'colsample_bytree': [1.0],
          'colsample_bylevel': [0.3],
          'subsample': [0.9],
          'gamma': [0],
          'lambda': [1],
          'alpha':[0],
          'min_child_weight':[1]
         }
grid_xgb_reg=GridSearchCV(xgb_reg,
                          param_grid=params,
                          scoring=scorer,
                          cv=5,
                          n_jobs=-1)
​
grid_xgb_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = grid_xgb_reg.predict(X_test)
y_train_pred = grid_xgb_reg.predict(X_train)

## Evaluate model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
​
print('RMSE  train: %.3f,  test: %.3f' %(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_pred)),np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))))
print('R^2   train: %.3f,  test: %.3f' %(r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred),r2_score(y_test, y_pred)))
```

The problem is the `GridSearchCV` does not seem to choose the best hyperparameters. In my case, when I set `max_depth` as `[2,3]`, The result is as follows. In the following case, `GridSearchCV` chose `max_depth:2` as the best hyper params.

```
#  The result when max_depth is 2
RMSE  train: 11.861,  test: 15.113
R^2   train: 0.817,  test: 0.601
```

However, if I updated `max_depth` to `[3]`(by getting rid of `2`), the test score is better than the previous value as follows.

```
#  The result when max_depth is 3
RMSE  train: 9.951,  test: 14.752
R^2   train: 0.871,  test: 0.620
```

### Question

My understanding is that even if I set `max_depth` as `[2,3]`, the `GridSearchCV` method SHOULD choose the `max_depth:3` as the best hyperparameters since `max_depth:3` can return the better score in terms of RSME or R^2 than `max_depth:2`. Could anyone tell me why my code cannot choose the best hyperparameters when I set `max_depth` as `[2,3]`?

Comment: The grid search chooses the best hyperparameters based on its internal cross-validation scores (have a look at its attribute `cv_results_`); the winner there isn't guaranteed to perform best on a new test set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run a second experiment with `max_depth:2`, then the results are not comparable to the first experiment with `max_depth:[2,3]` even for the run with `max_depth:2`, since there are sources of randomness in your code which you do not explicitly control, i.e. your code is not *reproducible*.

The first source of randomness is the CV folds; in order to ensure that the experiments will be run on identical splits of the data, you should define your GridSearchCV as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

seed_cv = 123 # any random value here

kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=seed_cv)

grid_xgb_reg=GridSearchCV(xgb_reg,
                          param_grid=params,
                          scoring=scorer,
                          cv=kf,   # <- change here
                          n_jobs=-1)
```

The second source of randomness is the XGBRegressor itself, which also includes a `random_state` argument (see the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRFRegressor)); you should change it to:

```
seed_xgb = 456 # any random value here (can even be the same with seed_cv)
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(random_state=seed_xgb)
```

But even with these arrangements, while your data splits will now be identical, the regression models built will not be necessarily so in the general case; here, if you keep the experiments like that, i.e. first with  `max_depth:[2,3]` and then with `max_depth:2`, the results will be identical indeed; but if you change it to, say,  first with  `max_depth:[2,3]` and then with `max_depth:3`, they will **not**, since in the first experiment, the run with `max_depth:3` will start with a different state of the random number generator (i.e. the one after the run with `max_depth:2` has finished).

There are limits to how identical you can make different runs under such conditions; for an example of a very subtle difference that nevertheless destroys the exact reproducibility between two experiments, see my answer in [Why does the importance parameter influence performance of Random Forest in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influence-performance-of-random-forest-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! You are saying that if I run `GridSearchCV` with `max_depth:[2,3]`, the result of `max_depth:3` is affected by the former result of `max_depth:2`, so the best hyper parameter would become  `max_depth:2`, am I correct? If yes, I would like to make each result identical. In that case, should I run the `for` loop and do my manual `GridSearch` like you explain in the another thread?

Comment: @shumach5 I did not say anything about best hyperparams; I only said that the results will not be identical with running a single run with `max_depth:3` , and I explained why. Unfortunately, not all experiments can be fully comparable in that sense, as I also mention - randomness enters from too many angles

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So the key factor that I missed was that the result is not identical.