# Is there any difference between preprocessing using pipeline and manually preprocessing columns in sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I was trying out the 30 days of ML Kaggle problem. I decided to use pipeline for preprocessing and all. But when I include preprocessor with pipeline, the rsme score becomes 0.75. But when I preprocess the columns manually (like the below code snippet), the rsme score is 0.72.

I've commented the pipeline used to get rsme score of 0.75

[Link to the kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/anandhakris/30daysofml)

```
preprocessor=ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('ord',OrdinalEncoder(),list(categorical_cols))])
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
final_predictions=[]
for fold in range(5):
    xtrain=X[X.kfold!=fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    xvalid=X[X.kfold==fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    xtest=test_data.copy()[total_cols]
    
    ytrain=xtrain.target
    yvalid=xvalid.target
    
    xtrain=xtrain[total_cols]
    xvalid=xvalid[total_cols]
    
    
    categorical_cols=list(categorical_cols)  

    xtrain[categorical_cols] = preprocessor.fit_transform(xtrain)
    xvalid[categorical_cols] = preprocessor.transform(xvalid)
    xtest[categorical_cols] = preprocessor.transform(xtest)
    
    
    model=XGBRegressor(n_jobs=4)
    my_pipeline=Pipeline(steps=[('model',model)])
    
#     my_pipeline=Pipeline(steps=[('pre',preprocessor),('model',model)])    
    
    my_pipeline.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
    
    
    preds_valid=my_pipeline.predict(xvalid)
    testpr=my_pipeline.predict(xtest)

    final_predictions.append(testpr)
    
    print(fold,mean_squared_error(yvalid,preds_valid,squared=False))
```

Comment: Why do you think using a pipeline is making a difference? Have you verified that both the test cases were exactly the same? Have you maintained the same datasets and seeds for both test cases?

Comment: Yes, I am feeding the same xtrain to both pipeline and Ordinal encoder and Yes I have set the random_state to 1.

I have put the link to the notebook in the question

Comment: You should also set seed on the `XGBRegressor` to ensure complete reproducibility.

Comment: As @AntoineDubuis says, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69429691/gridsearchcv-not-choosing-the-best-hyperparameters-for-xgboost