# Different cluster result with same random_state between versions 0.22.2 & 1.2.2

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, python-3.9, random-seed

I'm working on a clustering problem. To ensure result reproducibility, we initially set the `random_state` parameter in `KMeans()` to 0. However, after updating scikit-learn from version 0.22.2 to version 1.2.2, i encountered an unexpected issue. When i ran the same code with the same dataset , the results differed from our previous run. We are uncertain about the reasons behind this inconsistency and have been unable to reproduce the initial result.

Code:

```
model = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++', tol=0.0001, random_state=0, copy_x=True, algorithm='auto' )
```

**Expected Results**
Number of cluster = 5

```
    Cluster 1 | Cluster 2 | Cluster 3 | Cluster 4| cluster 5
            10| 20| 12| 30|45
```

**Actual Results**

***Version 0.22.2 :***
Number of cluster = 5

```
    Cluster 1 | Cluster 2 | Cluster 3 | Cluster 4| cluster 5
            10| 5| 6| 14|5
```

***Version 1.2.2 :***
Number of cluster = 5

```
    Cluster 1 | Cluster 2 | Cluster 3 | Cluster 4| cluster 5
            3| 7| 20| 8|2
```

Comment: I was checking (yes, one by one) older versions' changelogs and came across [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html#changed-models). Also [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.23.html#changed-models).

Comment: Source codes differ drastically between these versions. Slight changes in initialization / algorithm might result in different results. If it's important for you to find cause of these changes, you can check scikit-learn source code for these versions yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using init='k-means++' for initialization. Could this difference in initialization be attributed to the change between different versions of the library?

Comment: Weren't you using `k-means++` for the earlier version too?

Comment: Yes, i do. Actually, i use the k-means++

Comment: There is absolutely **no** reason why algorithms that include randomization should give identical results between different versions of any library, even with the same random seed.

Comment: To illustrate the sort of thing that @desertnaut is talking about, suppose that, in the new version of `kmeans`, they were to make a single extra call to `np.random.randint` for whatever reason.  Even assuming the same rng and the same seed, this would shift the entire sequence of random numbers up, resulting in what would apprear for all intents and purposes to be a totally different model initialization.

Comment: As @Him says; see what happens to a random forest when you include such an extra call to the random number generator (it is in R, but the lesson is the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224935/why-does-the-importance-parameter-influence-performance-of-random-forest-in-r/63468381#63468381

Comment: I might be wrong but there's no such change between `1.2.2` and `0.22.2`. See [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/compare/1.2.2...0.22.2.post1). Maybe some other underlying mechanism?